# Strapi GET request to /upload/files throws ERROR

Tags: debugging, strapi

### Reacreation

I should start by explaining what I've done to trigger this error:
1. Create a new Strapi App.
2. Create a **Collection-Type** with a **Media** Field.
3. Create a new **Entry** from this **Collection-Type** with a **File** uploaded.
4. Delete the **Media** Field from the **Collection-Type**.
5. Finally going to the Media Library (**GET request to /upload/files**) will result in an **ERROR**.

[see steps here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4uTt.jpg)

### FIX

I did find a fix to this situation, just Add the Media field back to the Collection-Type.
If you want to remove the Media field from the collection-type, remove it manually from its Entries first and then delete the Media field.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm your issue.

Can you please open a GitHub issue there - https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/new/choose

If you already have a fix, can you also submit a PR to fix it.

Thank you.